# Is it possible to use DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), skeleton); for android api level 14

Tags: android

Android 4.3 includes a new `getBestDateTimePattern()` method that automatically generates the best possible localized form of a Unicode UTS date for a locale that you specify. It’s a convenient way to provide a more localized experience for your users.

Is it possible to use `DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), skeleton);` for android api level 14.

May be how to implement the related/alternate method to `DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), skeleton);`

Comment: This method was added in API level 18, which gives you cannot use it in api level 14.

Comment: Is there any recommended alternative?

Comment: Yea if there's an open source library that can hold over, would be awesome if anyone knows about it.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the open source library that android uses to provide this functionality:
http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score -3):

This is a hack...

I using Android api level 19 to log what `DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), skeleton);` return
then replace 
`DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), skeleton);`
with the result in order to let Android api 14 run this code.(Hard coded but work)

Comment: Are you logging this for every locale? Otherwise you only have the pattern for en_US probably.

Comment: It's a hack, but I like it... I only need one format, I can live with hard-coded switch cases

Comment: seems like horrible solution